# groovy.sql.Sql error calling firstRow with Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, groovy

I'm using Groovy's groovy.sql.Sql to query an Oracle 10g database. It works very well, except for a strange problem I've been having with [firstRow](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#firstRow%28groovy.lang.GString%29). Essentially, I get a `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type` everytime I use it -- [eachRow](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#eachRow%28groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) works though.

Has anyone else run into this? If so, is there a workaround? This happens with Groovy 1.8.8 and 2.1.1. I've only tried this on Windows XP so far.

Example code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

// ojdbc14_ver_10_2_0_4.jar and orai18n_ver_10_2_0_4.jar is in the classpath
// Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit

sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbhost:1500:DBNAME", "user", "pass", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")


// This should return only one row (verified by querying the database).
// You can use any query that returns only one row.
String query = "select ITEM_A, ITEM_B, ITEM_C from MY_TBL where ITEM_D = 1233"

Long itemA = 0L
Long itemB = 0L, itemC = 0L

Integer rowCount = 0
sql.eachRow(query) { row ->
    itemA = row.ITEM_A
    itemB = row.ITEM_B
    itemC = row.ITEM_C
    rowCount++
}
assert rowCount <= 1 // 0 or 1 rows returned

println "Item A = $itemA"
println "Item B = $itemB"
println "Item C = $itemC"
// works fine

// now we have a problem:
sql.firstRow(query) { row ->
    itemA = row.ITEM_A
    itemB = row.ITEM_B
    itemC = row.ITEM_C
}
println "Item A = $itemA"
println "Item B = $itemB"
println "Item C = $itemC"
```

This results in the following output:

```
>>groovy firstRowTest.groovy
Item A = 640
Item B = 90
Item C = 90
25-Mar-2013 13:49:24 groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand execute
WARNING: Failed to execute:
                select ITEM_A, ITEM_B, ITEM_C from MY_TBL where ITEM_D = 1233
              because: Invalid column type
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9262)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8843)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9565)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9548)
        at firstRowTest.run(firstRowTest.groovy:30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstRow` doesn't take a Closure as a parameter, can you see if this gives the same error?

```
def frow = sql.firstRow(query)
itemA = frow.ITEM_A
itemB = frow.ITEM_B
itemC = frow.ITEM_C
```

I suspect, it's trying to [call this method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#firstRow-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-), and pass the Closure as the params

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could say:

```
sql.firstRow(query).with{row ->
    itemA = row.ITEM_A
    itemB = row.ITEM_B
    itemC = row.ITEM_C     
}
```

This does allow you to pass in a closure on the GroovyRowResult that is returned from the firstRow method.

Comment: This'll work too (and is more readable) but you'll get a NullPointerException if your query returns 0 rows.